# Determining quadratic residues quickly

Tags: elementary-number-theory, self-learning, quadratic-residues

Let's say that I'm looking for all quadratic residues of a number.  THe example from my book is 31.  So I can just evaluate $i^2\equiv{a}\pmod{31}$, for $i=1..15$.  While not a terribly difficult task, this seems to take a while for large moduli.  Is there, other than writing an algorithm on a computer program, a quick way to determine just exactly which numbers are residues and non-residues?  Are there patterns for particular numbers like composite vs. prime, specific multiples carry particular types of residues?

EDIT:  I should mentioned that I already know how to show the existence of residues using Euler's criterion / the Legendre symbol.  I'm specifically looking for a tip/method to determine the actual residues other than "plug and chug".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, $31$ is prime, so you want to check if the Legendre symbol of $a$ is $1$. If it is, then if you manage to find a primitive root $\pmod{31}$, you can use this primitive root to find a quadratic residue for $a$. A primitive root is simply a generator for the group of units of $\mathbb F_p$, i.e. the integers $\pmod p$ with $0$ removed.

Therefore you want algorithms that find primitive roots fast, assuming you work modulo a large prime power (or modulo some number which admits a primitive root, I don't remember exactly the characterization). I'm afraid I'm not a specialist in those algorithms, but I know the literature is out there.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thank you.  I should have mentioned that I already learned the Legendre symbol for existence.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: @ChristopherErnst : You can still edit your question to say so. I would not be surprised if someone gave a better answer than me.

Comment: Thanks again.  I will do that!